# Change return type of function based on class

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a class `BaseViewController:UIViewController`, and I want a way to instantiate this viewController from a Xib, I could do it like this:

```
class func initFromXib()->BaseViewController?{
    let nibName = String(NSStringFromClass(self).split(separator: ".").last ?? "")
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? BaseViewController
}
```

Whenever I need the ViewController initialized from xib, I could then just say `let vc = BaseViewController.initFromXib()`.

But let's say I have a subclass of this viewController, named `HomeViewController:BaseViewController`. 
If I say `let home = HomeViewController.initFromXib()`, this would indeed successfully return an instance of `HomeViewController` (as long as there's a Xib named as such), but as a `BaseViewController`. There's nothing wrong with this, all I have to do is

```
let vc = HomeViewController.initFromXib() as? HomeViewController
```

and everything is coolioo. But is there a way to make the return type of the `initFromXib` a "generic" type of the class it stems from, so that `initFromXib` always returns the type of the correct class?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Answer (score 2):

A solution is a protocol extension with associated type, just adopt the protocol in the appropriate classes

```
protocol XibInitializable {
    associatedtype ControllerType : UIViewController = Self
    static func initFromXib() -> ControllerType?
}

extension XibInitializable where Self : UIViewController {

    static func initFromXib() -> ControllerType? {
        let nibName = String(describing: Self.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? ControllerType
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
let vc = HomeViewController.initFromXib()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generics

```
class func initFromXib<T: BaseViewController>()-> T?{
    let nibName = String(NSStringFromClass(self).split(separator: ".").last ?? "")
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? T
}
```

Comment: When using this, I get the return type BaseViewController as I already do, not HomeViewController. Do I need to call it in some special way to set what T is? Like `HomeViewController.initFromXib<HomeViewController>()`? I can't get that working either.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below solution, You don't need to even use the Generics and TypeCasting as well.

```
extension UIViewController {

    static func initWithNibName() -> Self {
        return self.init(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

**How to use in code?**

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController.initWithNibName()
print(homeVC) // type is HomeViewController
```

Comment: This crashes with `Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class BaseViewController`. If I implement this initializer and simply call super.init(nibName:bundle) (in either or both Base and Home), I get an uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: @Sti, This Method is only for get the instance of XIB, not the storyboard. Just an update. And BTW I am not getting any crash as I used it in my daily basis.